# What's Kotlin equivalent of Promise.all with types?

Tags: kotlin

In typescript, I can do the following:

```
const [myNumber, myString] = await Promise.all([firstFunction(), secondFunction()])
```

Typescript will be intelligent enough to detect that the firstFunction returns a number, second function returns a string, and assign types accordingly.

I searched on the internet, and it suggested the following for Kotlin:

```
val (myNumber, myString) = coroutineScope {
            arrayOf(async {
                firstFunction()
            }, async {
                secondFunction()
            }).map  {it.await() }
        }
```

However, this doesn't work. Both variables are typed as Any. Is there any workaround here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists and arrays won't work because they are typed to a common type of all elements, as you discovered.

Kotlin has 2- and 3-parameter tuples built in, called Pair and Triple. You can use these tuples to have typed parameters returned for destructuring. Any more than 3, and you have to create your own class or use a library that has higher-sized tuples provided. The other common solution is to make a specific `data class` for your use case.

There's no built-in `awaitAll` function for tuples, but you could make one.

```
suspend fun <A, B> Pair<Deferred<A>, Deferred<B>>.awaitAll(): Pair<A, B> {
    val (a, b) = listOf(first, second).awaitAll()
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return Pair(a, b) as Pair<A, B>
}

val (myNumber, myString) = coroutineScope {
    Pair(
        async { firstFunction() },
        async { secondFunction() }
    ).awaitAll()
}
```

---

A simpler implementation of `awaitAll()` without casting is possible, but the above throws an error faster if the second function has an error before the first function is complete.

```
suspend fun <A, B> Pair<Deferred<A>, Deferred<B>>.awaitAll(): Pair<A, B> =
    Pair(first.await(), second.await())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your coroutine is returning a list, and you are doing a destructured declaration to get the first 2 elements from this list as named values, ignoring the rest of the list.

Lists in Java are parameterized and, unless you explicitly state the type, they will be parameterized by the most common root type shared by all members of the list. In this case, that is whatever the shared root type of the return values of `firstFunction` and `secondFunction` are.

Given that you have not provided the function signatures of either of these functions, we can just assume they are different, therefore your list will be parameterized with the shared root type, which will be `Comparable<Nothing>` (not `Any` as your question states - see SO rules, this question is actually breaking the rules of this forum).

Comment: What rule is the question breaking? How is type erasure relevant here, and why would my answer not work? Maybe I'm misunderstanding what the OP wants to accomplish.

Comment: Minimum reproducable code - the code provided in question will not even compile without some extra work. In addition, the OP states that the inferred type is `Any` when it is in fact `Comparable<Nothing>`, so the error is misleading (again this would be avoided if the rule about posting actual minimum reproducible code was adhered to). And type erasure is relevant here as this is the reason why the OP's desired behavior of the language is not matching with the reality of the language (i.e. the compiler being able to infer the types in the destructured declaration)

Comment: Even without type erasure like in C#, the problem would remain because a collection's elements are only retrieved as the type declared for the whole collection. But tuples solve it regardless of whether the language has type erasure because it is typed per element.

Comment: I interpret that rule differently. "Shortest code necessary to reproduce" doesn't mean the entirety of the code to reproduce is included in the question, just enough that we could reproduce the error from the information given relatively easily. And that rule only applies to questions asking for debugging help, which this question does not.

Comment: You are correct about the type erasure, it is not relevant. I'll amend my answer. Your answer probably addresses the OP's actual requirement better than mine in any case (as they only seem to care about the first 2 elements of the list, indicating they really wanted a Pair instead of a list in the first place...)